# Approximation of continuous functions by polynomials on $[1,\infty)$.

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to prove the following proposition:

> Let $f:[1,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$ exists. Show that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a polynomial $p = p(\epsilon)$ such that $|f(x) - p(\frac{1}{x})| < \epsilon$ for all $x\in[1,\infty)$.

It is quite confusing that the polynomial is evaluated on $1/x$ and not on $x$. Moreover, how can we be so sure that such polynomial exists? Any ideas/feedback/observations would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $g(x)=f(1/x)$ for $x\ne 0$, $g(0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$ and apply Weierstrass Theorem.

Comment: Just a comment, one may need to check $g$ for continuity. This step, although trivial, would be necessary.

Comment: @MathUser, true, thanks for the clarifiction.

Answer (score 0):

Consider polynomial approximations of the function $$x\mapsto \begin{cases}f(1/x)&\text{if $0<x\le 1$}\\\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)&\text{if $x=0$}\end{cases} $$
on the intrerval $[0,1]$